# Scrolling Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe

I have two windows: One is a page meant to be in an iframe, and one is the page meant to house the iframe. The objective of my project is to make an iframe that scrolls, but, when it is moused over, it pauses. I currently have the following code for the page meant to be in an iframe: 
http://dabbler.org/edit/asdf/scrolling/index.html
and the code for the page meant to house the iframe:
http://dabbler.org/edit/asdf/scrolling/index2.html

What is wrong with my code? (Yes, I know I don't have body, head, HTML and the others, that isn't the problem, for those are thrust in automatically when the page is interpreted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window.onmouseover and window.onmouseout are not defined correctly.

You have this:

```
 window.onmouseout = pageScroll();     
 window.onmouseover = unpageScroll();
```

You want to do this:

```
 window.onmouseout = pageScroll;     
 window.onmouseover = unpageScroll;
```

You were setting onmouseout, and onmouseover to the return values of calling pageScroll and unpageScroll, but you wanted to set onmouseout/onmouseover the functions pageScroll and unpageScroll.

And finally, you're calling the wrong function in your `setTimeout`.

You are calling pageScroll, but you want to be calling `pageScroller`, which does the actual scrolling.

**EDIT**

```
 function pageScroll(){
            num = 150;
            clearTimeout(scrolldelay);
            pageScroller();
 }
  function unpageScroll(){num = 15000000;}
  function pageScroller() {
    window.scrollBy(0,50); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
    scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroller()',num); // scrolls every 100 millisecond
  }
  var num = 50;
  window.onmouseout = pageScroll;
  window.onmouseover = unpageScroll;
```

BTW, you should handle calling clearTimeout in pageScroller at some point in the future when the page is scrolled vertically as much as possible.  There's no point in continuing to call scrollBy if the window is already scrolled as much as possible.

Comment: It still does not work the way I would like it too - why is it that on mouseout it does not scroll normally again?

Comment: You need to clear the long timeout and call pageScroller() again, see  EDIT in answer above